# Calling Java exe from .NET Windows application using command

Tags: java, c#, command-line

Loosing Chinese character when I call Java exe from .net (windows app) using command line argument

I am calling Java exe using process object (passing argument) on .net(Windows app) and when I read command line argument in Java main function, it gets converted as "????"
 both applications (Java and .net) running on same windows machine

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath + "\\Java_App.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "<soapenv:Body><tem:Add><tem:intA>你好嗎)</tem:intA><tem:intB>你好嗎)</tem:intB></tem:Add></soapenv:Body> 你好嗎.txt";
Process p1 = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

I expect same Chinese characters in Java side instead of "????"

Comment: What’s your computers code page set to?

Comment: My computer code page is 437

Comment: Yeah that won’t have the Chinese characters you want.  You’ll need to switch your code page OR try something I haven’t used yet. In windows there is a check box for enabling UTF8, try enabling it, restart your PC and try again. The check box can be found at Control Panel > Region > Administrative > Change system locale...

Comment: Also, you’ll probably have to convert the c# UTF16 string to UTF8 before passing it to the Arguments property

Comment: I tried both options as you suggested but both approach is not working. After changing code page, i got garbage character in java application instead of "?".

Comment: I’m unsure what java uses as it’s string encoding. Another test, can you read that string you’re attempting to pass via the command line from a file instead (from the Java application)?